# Case Home Page not displaying correctly

Tags: visualforce, case, tab, home-page-component

Problem: I want to override the Case tab with a Visualforce page , but send Users who click a Visualforce page Tab "Case List Views" to the standard Salesforce.com Case home page.

My problem is similar to the one presented here:

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/overriding-a-page-for-some-but-not-all-users

Whn I click the Case List Views Tab, I am presented with not the standard Salesforce.com Case Home Page, but rather a "blank" page that shows the salesforce header and navigation and *nothing* in the pane.

[image: Case home page with *nothing* displayed]

Here's my code for my Visualforce page that runs when Users click the "Case List Views" Tab:

```
<apex:page >

<script>

function launchWindow()

{

window.open("/apex/Case_consolidated_View_2?CaseListViews='yes'");

}

</script>


</apex:page>
```

And here's my code for the Case_consolidated_view_2 Visualforce page that I am 1) overriding the Cases Tab with and 2) opens in the new window when you click the "Case List Views" Tab:

```
<apex:page action="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.CaseListViews != 'yes' , null,urlFor($Action.Case.Tab , $ObjectType.Case , null, true))}" >


<apex:enhancedList listId="00B80000008pq6U" height="600" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25"/>

</apex:page>
```

Let me know where I am going wrong and how I can get the Cases home page to display correctly when the User clicks the "Case List Views" Tab. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the entire code for Case List Views? You have one script statement and never call it anywhere. I would expect this code to render the blank page you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, that is the entire code for Case_List_Views . The cookbook recipe above seems to indicate that the page Case_consolidated_view_2 is what renders the Standard Case Home Page if conditions are met, and my custom enhanced list if conditions are not met.

Comment: The page you have for Case_List_Views has nothing on it, you are seeing a blank page because you never load your second page.

Comment: @CyberJus Why? and what do you suggest I do instead?